# Get command executed by python mysql connector

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I am using mysql connector with python, and sometimes when debugging I would like to see what command the cursor have executed exactly.
I have things like this:

```
 ajout="UPDATE campagne_detail set fait_CAMD=1 WHERE id=%s and ca=%s"
 val=(a,b)
 cursor.execute(ajout,val)
```

How can I do to see exactly what command it sent to mysql?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After executing the statement, call

```
sql = cursor.statement
```

`sql` will be the string sent to the MySQL server.